# How to rename file during copy in command prompt

Tags: command-line, batch, bash-scripting, rename

I want copy a file from a folder to another while changing the file name.
How can I do this?

For example: copy `1.txt` to `C:\new folder` with this name: `2.bat`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's pretty straightforward with the [copy](https://ss64.com/nt/copy.html) command:

```
copy folder1\1.txt folder2\2.bat
```